# Painting data from device context

Tags: winapi, canvas, gdi

I've just got a fresh [device context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface#Technical_details) (DC):

```
GetDC(someForeignHwnd)
```

Most normal people now want to paint on this. I don't. I want to display the context in my own program. Or duplicate, I wouldn't even mind the window I stole the context from beeing empty.

In my case, I want it in a `TPanel` in [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_%28language%29), but anything else helping me understanding goes.

Afterwards, I'll probably find the DC invalid by the time I get to display it.

My main problem is: Showing the content of another window in my own. But that isn't important. First of all, I want to know how these DC are of any use. Can I do something like the following?

```
Canvas.Draw(0, 0, MyNewDC);
```

The answer can be in [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), or [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29). Is it just not possible or just a stupid idea?

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible to use a device context that you retrieve via `GetDC()` as the SOURCE for `BitBlt()`, etc., you will likely not get the results that you're looking for.  When you call `GetDC()` for a specific window, Windows essentially returns a device context for the screen, but with a clipping region set to exclude any portions of the screen where the window is not visible.  For example, if there happens to be another window overlapping the source window, the portion of the source window that is covered is clipped from the device context.  Therefore, you can only "retrieve" the bits that are actually visible.

You may have better luck sending a `WM_PRINT` or `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message to the window.  However, not all windows respond to these messages, so this isn't a universal solution.